# Error when using RecordWildCards extension from GHCi

Tags: haskell, record, ghci

I have created a function that uses the `RecordWildCards` syntax for pattern matching on a Haskell record type:

**Pragmas**

I have placed the pragmas at the top of the file. I have also tried adding it with `:set -XRecordWildCards`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
```

**Type definitions**

```
data ClientR = GovOrgR { clientRName :: String }
                | CompanyR { clientRName :: String,
                            companyId   :: Integer,
                            person      :: PersonR,
                            duty        :: String
                          }
                | IndividualR { person :: PersonR }
                deriving Show

data PersonR = PersonR {
                          firstName :: String,
                          lastName  :: String
                       } deriving Show
```

**Function**

```
greet2 :: ClientR -> String
greet2 IndividualR { person = PersonR { .. } } = "hi" ++ firstName ++ " " ++ lastName + " "
greet2 CompanyR { .. } = "hello " ++ firstName ++ " " ++ lastName ++ "who works as a " ++ duty ++ " " ++ clientRName + " "
greet2 GovOrgR {} = "Welcome"
```

**Error**

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’
                  with actual type ‘PersonR -> String’
    • Probable cause: ‘lastName’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘lastName’
      In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely
        ‘lastName ++ "who works as a " ++ duty ++ " " ++ clientRName + " "’
      In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely
        ‘" "
         ++
           lastName ++ "who works as a " ++ duty ++ " " ++ clientRName + " "’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

When I use this function on `CompanyR` to match the `PersonR` using `as pattern`, I get:

**Function**

```
greet2 c@(CompanyR { .. }) = "hello " ++ (firstName $ person c) ++ " " ++ (lastName $ person c)
```

**Error**

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘ClientR -> PersonR’
                  with actual type ‘PersonR’
    • The function ‘person’ is applied to one argument,
      but its type ‘PersonR’ has none
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘person c’
      In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘(firstName $ person c)’

    • Couldn't match expected type ‘ClientR -> PersonR’
                  with actual type ‘PersonR’
    • The function ‘person’ is applied to one argument,
      but its type ‘PersonR’ has none
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘person c’
      In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘(lastName $ person c)’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it right in your first case here (although I fixed a `++` where you had `+`):

```
greet2 :: ClientR -> String
greet2 IndividualR { person = PersonR { .. } } = "hi" ++ firstName ++ " " ++ lastName ++ " "
```

But here `firstName` etc are not records in `CompanyR` so `CompanyR { .. }` does not bring them into scope:

```
greet2 CompanyR { .. } = "hello " ++ firstName ++ " " ++ lastName ++ "who works as a " ++ duty ++ " " ++ clientRName + " "
```

You have to do something like you did in the first case of `greet2`, just above:

```
greet2 CompanyR {person = PersonR { .. }, .. } = "hello " ++ firstName ++ " " ++ lastName ++ "who works as a " ++ duty ++ " " ++ clientRName ++ " "
```

Comment: I am trying `greet2 c@(CompanyR { .. }) = "hello " ++ (firstName $ person c) ++ " " ++ (lastName $ person c) ` to get person out of the `CompayR` type using `RecordWildCards`.